# keras very slow compared to low level TF?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I had a curious experience with Keras. 
Info: input dataset shapes

16 features, 5000 observations
target variable: 1 dimension

Problem: **Regression**

While writing code for students I developed a toy network using tf using the following code (I know is not a complete example but I hope it will give you enough information)

```
n1 = 15 # Number of neurons in layer 1
n2 = 15 # Number of neurons in layer 2 
n3 = 15
nx = number_of_x_points
n_dim = nx
n4 = 1

stddev_f = 0.1

tf.set_random_seed(5)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n_dim, None])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, None])
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n1, n_dim], stddev=stddev_f)) 
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape = [n1,1]) )
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n2, n1], stddev=stddev_f)) 
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape = [n2,1])) 
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n3,n2], stddev = stddev_f))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape = [n3,1]))
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n4,n3], stddev = stddev_f))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape = [n4,1]))


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [nx, None]) # Inputs
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None]) # Labels


Z1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W1, X) + b1) # n1 x n_dim * n_dim x n_obs = n1 x n_obs
Z2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W2, Z1) + b2) # n2 x n1 * n1 * n_obs = n2 x n_obs
Z3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(W3, Z2) + b3)
Z4 = tf.matmul(W4, Z3) + b4
y_ = tf.sigmoid(Z4)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_-Y))
learning_rate = 0.005
training_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

training_epochs = 1000
cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1], dtype = float)
cost_meas_history = np.empty(shape=[1], dtype = float)

train_x = np.transpose(data)
train_y = np.transpose(targets)

cost_history = []
for epoch in range(training_epochs+1):

    for i in range(0, train_x.shape[0], batch_size):
        x_batch = train_x[i:i + batch_size,:]
        y_batch = train_y[i:i + batch_size,:]

        sess.run(training_step, feed_dict = {X: x_batch, Y: y_batch})

    cost_ = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={ X:train_x, Y: train_y})
    cost_history = np.append(cost_history, cost_)

    if (epoch % 5000 == 0):
        print("Reached epoch",epoch,"cost J =", cost_)
```

this code is working quite well and it takes on my laptop for 1000 epochs 5 sec. Now I developed the same network with keras with the code

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(15, input_dim=16, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='sigmoid'))

model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.005),
          loss='mse',
          metrics=['mae'])

# Training Phase
model.fit(train_x.transpose(), train_y.transpose()/100.0, epochs=1000, batch_size=100,verbose = 0)
```

This code takes 43 sec. Has anyone any idea what this is the case? Now I expected Keras to be slower but not **that** much slower. What am I missing?

Thanks, Umberto

Comment: Make your examples reproducible please. Add the code for generating (dummy) data and specify the values of variables. So that we only need to just copy, paste and run it, without the need to do any modifications.

Comment: Yep... Will try to do that... But is kind of difficult. Thanks for replying.

Comment: BTW, just by looking at your codes it seems that the TF model contains four Dense layers and the Keras model contains three dense layers.

Comment: Sorry... forgot the line ```model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))```. Added...

Comment: Oh! It seems you have not pasted the Keras code properly. The last layer have been merged(!!!) to the previous layer.

Comment: It needs further editing. Look at the forth line of Keras code and scroll to the right.

Comment: My apologies... I updated the code. I am really sorry...

Comment: Both take the same amount of time on my machine (`data` shape: (1000,1000), `targets` shape: `(1000, 1)`). Make sure `verbose=0` when fitting the model in Keras. Further, you have set the last axis as the samples axis (i.e. `[nx, None]` and `[1, None]`). Therefore, fetching batch data must be also be done on the last axis: `train_x[:, i:i + batch_size]` and `train_y[:, i:i + batch_size]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the reason... It was my mistake. Due to a series of mistakes, due to programming at night after midnight (...), I realized I was comparing batch GD and mini-batch GD. My apologies to everyone and thanks to today that noticed my mistake...
If someone thinks this should be deleted is fine with me.

Now Keras and plain TF are taking exactly the same time. Thanks everyone for reading.

Best, Umberto